# Extracting common chunks amongst multiple compiler configurations in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying out the multi-compiler option in webpack and am following the [example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler) at their github. However, I can't seem to understand how I can split out the common code amongst the multiple configurations.

For example, I may have same vendor libraries used in the different set of configurations. I would like to have these shared codes to be bundled to one single common file.

I tried the following but it ended up creating an individual bundles of the `vendors` entry for each compile configuration.

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = [
    {
        name: "app-mod1",
        entry: {
            vendors: ['jquery', 'react', 'react-dom'],
            pageA: ['./mod1/pageA'],
            pageB: ['./mod1/pageB']
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "/mod1/js"),
            filename: "[name].bundle.js"
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: ['vendors'],
                minChunks: Infinity
            })
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "app-mod2",
        entry: {
            vendors: ['lodash', 'react', 'react-dom'],
            pageA: ['./mod2/pageA'],
            pageB: ['./mod2/pageB']
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "/mod2/js"),
            filename: "[name].bundle.js"
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: ['vendors'],
                minChunks: Infinity
            })
        ]
    }
];
```

Since react, react-dom are shared between the 2 compilations, my intention is for them to be bundled as a single file which can be shared instead of creating a same bundle for each compilation.

How can I extract the common chunks out of multiple compiler configurations?

Comment: Carven did you find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Bulkan unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: I've hit this problem as well. Perhaps we need to use [dll-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/) ?

Comment: @Bulkan I have tried dll-plugin but it didn't quite work the way I wanted. It is close but still not exactly what I needed. If I remember correctly, one of the problem was tracking the versioning in the meta file. The hash gets changed even though a particular entry is shared and unchanged.

Comment: I found this [article](https://medium.com/webpack/predictable-long-term-caching-with-webpack-d3eee1d3fa31) which has helped me create a vendor file.  I think the trick for you is to create another chunk that only has `react` and `react-dom`.

Comment: `DllPlugin` can't be used for production. Probably your vendors have to be the same, across the board.

Comment: buddy help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234817/how-do-we-extract-css-chunks-file-in-laravel-with-vue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Brief answer

**You can't do that job in the way you want.**

### TL;DR

@Carven, I am afraid that you can't achieve your goal via `MultiCompiler` of Webpack, `MultiCompiler` is not meant to do that job, at least for the near feature.

See [the source code for initiating the MultiCompiler instance](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/bcde5195096102070ddf40a40a88fdf58e08f693/lib/webpack.js#L23), it actually initiates separate `Compiler` instances. These compiler have no data shared between.

See also [the source of running MultiCompiler instance](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/bcde5195096102070ddf40a40a88fdf58e08f693/lib/MultiCompiler.js#L147), the compilers instance also run separately without sharing data.

The only thing these compilers share is the `Stats` instance they produce and merge into a `MultiStats`.

By the way, there is no clue in [the example you mentioned](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/bcde5195096102070ddf40a40a88fdf58e08f693/examples/multi-compiler) that some modules are shared between multi-compilers.

### Alternative

As described by @Tzook-Bar-Noy, IMHO, you have to use muti-entries to achieve MPA(Multi-page Application) bundling.

#### Other worth mentioning

I noticed a library called [webpack-multi-configurator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-multi-configurator) is using the multi-compiler feature. But I don't think it will share common chunk(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the shared code into another compilation, and bundle it with DllBundlesPlugin.
later consume this DLL via DLLReferencePlugin and add it to your page either manually or via HTMLWebpackPlugin's [add-asset-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/SimenB/add-asset-html-webpack-plugin/)

Bolierplate can be reduced by using [autodll-webpack-Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autodll-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

I learned about it now, and this topic seems quite hard to understand in webpack docs. I managed to create something that works, as it created 2 separate files and extracted the common dependencies to another file.

Here is my webpack config:

```
{
    entry: {

        pageA: "./first/first",
        pageB: "./second/second"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["vendor", "common"],
        })
    ]
};
```

the output of this will be:

```
./js/
    common.js
    vendor.js
    pageA.js
    pageB.js
```

I created a repo with the example I worked on: https://github.com/tzookb/webpack-common-vendor-chunks

when I open a new html file I load these files:

```
 first page:
     common.js
     vendor.js
     pageA.js

 sec page:
     common.js
     vendor.js
     pageB.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your webpack configuration is not using the [multi compiler](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler) feature.

Comment: you don't have to have an array of configs. This is the how to extract common libraries. For what you requested, the job is done, and it compiles multiple files so its there

Comment: the question specifically relates to an array of configs. In my case I need to use an array of config objects as the output path is changed based on the entry file.

Comment: @Bulkan ok so what is your end goal? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My goal is I want the original question above to be answered.

Comment: Well I'm trying to help, but if this is the way you respond, so good luck :)

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with my comment above. I apologise If I caused any misunderstanding.

Comment: I just want to understand better what files you haves and what do you want to get in the end... maybe it could help others to help you as well. As you can see not much response yet